# I need to create a bash script that will run byobu, then in the background continue running and do things

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, byobu

What I'm trying to do is basically this:

- start byobu in the foreground when the script runs
- have the rest of the script run in the background and use byobu cmdline syntax to pass commands and keystrokes to the byobu instance in the foreground.

I have an existing fairly contrived script that does a bunch of stuff with screen splits and keystroke injection but the part I can't figure out is "How to launch byobu up front, so the user can watch it all happen from behind the proverbial bulletproof glass"

Comment: Sounds simple enough. Which part is causing you problems? Please show your minimal code and say what's wrong. Not sure what the bullet-proof glass bit means. Thank you.

Comment: i described it this way because i don't know how to write the code to do what I'm after. Right now the script just launches byobu at the end, but this is a compromise until I can sort out how to have it run the way I want.